# Button click using combination of text and id Robit framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework, xpath-2.0

In robit framework i am doing a button click based on text but i want to add ID also as the page has multiple button with same text

```
path="//button[text()=open]
```

Here i want to add id also
what to do ?
Tried following but not worked

```
path="//button[text()=open, id=23]
path="//button[text()=open, @id=23]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path="//button[@id='23'][text()='open']"
```

or

```
path="//button[@id='23' and text()='open']"
```

You can add as many conditions as you like, be sure to check xpath rules, they are easy.

But reviewing your question, I'm pretty sure id's are unique in a document, you might not need anything except the ID.